# Postfix not attaching file from script

Tags: postfix, asterisk

I'm trying to send an asterisk voice recording out via email using the script found [here](http://community.freepbx.org/t/solved-how-to-email-call-recordings-post-call-recording-script/26747/6) but instead of sending the file, it just puts the path to the file at the top of the email sent. I believe all the permissions are correct and the log files aren't showing any errors. I was hoping someone could help me troubleshoot this further.

The file name for the attachment appears to be correct when I run ls -lrt against the file at the top of the email. Is there any way to get postfix to add more verbosity to its logs?

The script

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script emails the recorded call right after the call is hung up. Below are    the variables passed through asterisk
# $1 - year
# $2 - month
# $3 - day
# $4 - Time String
# $5 - Source
# $6 - File
# $7 - Destination
# $dt - Date and Time


dt=$(date '+%m/%d/%Y %r');


echo -e "You have a new call recording to listen to \n\n
 The call date and time was $dt \n\n 
 The call was from $5 \n\n
 The call was to $7 \n\n

 Please see the attached file \n\n" | mail -a /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/$1/$2/$3/$6 -s "New Call Recording" email@domain.com
```

Which sends out the following email

Heading "New Call Recording"

```
/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/2016/02/11/internal-99-101-20160211-123644-1455154604.21.wav

You have a new call recording to listen to 


The call date and time was 02/11/2016 12:36:53 PM 


The call was from 101 


The call was to 99 



Please see the attached file
```

ps - aux shows Asterisk is running as its own user

## ps -aux | grep asterisk

```
asterisk   619  0.0  0.8 314092  8532 ?        S    12:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
asterisk   621  0.0  0.8 314092  8532 ?        S    12:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
asterisk   622  0.0  0.8 314092  8532 ?        S    12:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
asterisk   623  0.0  0.8 314092  8532 ?        S    12:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
asterisk   624  0.0  0.8 314092  8532 ?        S    12:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
asterisk   971  1.2  4.9 1855636 50188 ?       Ssl  12:26   0:15 /usr/sbin/asterisk -U asterisk -G asterisk
```

The mail.log file shows the user asterisk is the account which is sending the outbound mail.

## /var/log# cat mail.log

```
Feb 11 12:36:07 APSPBX postfix/pickup[1172]: 9B54061A6B: uid=1001 from=<asterisk>
Feb 11 12:36:07 APSPBX postfix/cleanup[1701]: 9B54061A6B: message-id=<20160211013607.9B54061A6B@APSPBX>
Feb 11 12:36:07 APSPBX postfix/qmgr[1173]: 9B54061A6B: from=<asterisk@APSPBX>, size=619, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 11 12:36:22 APSPBX postfix/smtp[1644]: 9B54061A6B: to=<email@domain.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.72.108]:587, delay=15, delays=0.02/0/13/1.8, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1455154590 s21sm7891538pfi.29 - gsmtp)
Feb 11 12:36:22 APSPBX postfix/qmgr[1173]: 9B54061A6B: removed
```

The folder and files which postfix is trying to get the attachment for are owned by the asterisk user.

## ls -lrt /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/2016/02/11/

```
total 484
-rw-r--r-- 1 asterisk asterisk 139564 Feb 11 12:34 internal-99-101-20160211-123412-1455154452.7.wav
-rw-r--r-- 1 asterisk asterisk 213164 Feb 11 12:36 internal-99-101-20160211-123554-1455154554.14.wav
-rw-r--r-- 1 asterisk asterisk 135084 Feb 11 12:36 internal-99-101-20160211-123644-1455154604.21.wav
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using the [GNU Mailutils](http://man.cx/mail%281%29) where the `-a` option means appends a header (see below).

> −a, −−append=HEADER: VALUE append given header to the message being
>   sent

As for the [mailx](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mailx) utility the `-a` option refers to an attachment:

> -a file
>
> Attach the given file to the message.

So check your OS and the distribution package you are using. With command like `man mail`, you can find out yourself, which mail command you are using and what the -a option means.

For an alternative solution, you can just use the `mutt` command:

```
echo "Here goes the message body....." | mutt -a "/path/to/attachment_file" -s "Subject.." -- recipient@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks, it was an easy fix, the only change was adding the -- before the email address.